# Java eval javascript wont run public method

Tags: java, javascript, eval

The creating and setting values works but whenever i try to do the Triangle.add() or say t.add() to add it to the list (which works when not done through javascript) it doesnt work. heres the javascript code to eval

```
    public String code = "" +
        "" +
        "var v = vector;" +
        "v.x = 0;" +
        "v.y = 0;" +
        "v.z = 0;" +
        "var v1 = vector;" +
        "v1.x = 100;" +
        "v1.y = 100;" +
        "v1.z = 100;" +
        "var v2 = vector;" +
        "v2.x = 200;" +
        "v2.y = 200;" +
        "v2.z = 200;" +
        "" +
        "var t = triangle;" +
        "t.a = v;" +
        "t.b = v1;" +
        "t.c = v2;" +
        "t.add();" +
        "print('hey');" +
        "print(t.b.x);" +
        "t.add();" +
        "";
```

and heres the java code which evals it

```
public void run() {
    try { 
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName ("rhino");
        engine.put("vector", new Vector3f());
        engine.put("triangle", new Triangle(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,TextureHandler.getHeldTexture(),false));
        engine.eval(code);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information around what you mean by "doesn't work". Is there a stacktrace? Can you post it?

Comment: no stack trace. heres the add() method
` public void add() {
  if (!triangles.contains(this)) {
   triangles.add(this);
  }
 }`

Comment: So what's "not working"?

Comment: heres an update. i added a print to the add method and that functions but the actual adding it to the list doesnt
` public void add() {
  if (!triangles.contains(this)) {
   triangles.add(this);
  }
  System.out.println(this.b.x);
 }`

Comment: Ah. what is the "triangles" list? does it exist in the javascript context? I'm not super familiar with rhino, but I doubt you can modify the context of a list in javascript if the list only exists in the java context.

Comment: wait nevermind the print doesnt function ether. i was confusing it with something else. so nothing works, no error, and its not helping me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68577/discussion-between-paul-r-and-tyler-songer).

Comment: u asked heres my answer. the list is in the triangles class. in the javascript then i do t.add() it should do the method in the java its self but it doesnt seem to carry the data over to java maybe?